# how can I do a get latest on a remote branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

I am trying to catchup with the latest code from a remote github branch. Suppose this branch is called myDevBranch how can I get this locally? I tried:

```
git fetch myDevBranch
```

This returns :

```
fatal: 'myDevBranch' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Looks like a securuty issue or is there another way of getting the remote branch locally?

Comment: **Hint:** `'myDevBranch' does not appear to be a git repository`. Read up about how `git fetch` is called: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't fetch a branch, you [`fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) a remote, so the correct line would be

```
git fetch origin # or whatever your remote is called
```

Then the all tracking branches are updated, your updated code will be it a branch called `origin/myDevBranch`, again origin is replaced with your upstream name

To update your local branch you can merge the upstream `git merge origin/myDevBranch` but you need to make sure that your `HEAD` is pointing to your local branch of this remote (aka myDevBranch),

Or you can checkout to it `git checkout origin/myDevBranch` but that would leave you in a [detached head mode](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head), you can create a new local branch from that remote using `git checkout -b`

If your `HEAD` is pointing to your current branch, then you can do a [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull), keep in mind that `pull` will do both `fetch` and `merge`, and if your branch has [diverged](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell#divergent_history) for any reason you would get a [`conflict`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#_basic_merge_conflicts) that you will need to resolve by your self.

If you need to [`rebase`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) then you could either do a manual `fetch` and `rebase` or you could do a [`git pull --rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#git-pull---rebasefalsetruepreserveinteractive)

Comment: you can also use `git pull` to get the whatever is there in the remote branch in your computer. It _Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch. In its default mode, `git pull` is shorthand for `git fetch` followed by git `merge FETCH_HEAD`._ Source: [https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull]

Comment: Thanks @ParamvirSinghKarwal, you're correct indeed, I'll update my answer

Comment: You can also use ```git fetch -vp``` to show the verbose progress, ie what branches are up to date and what has been updated